# set autocommit=0 do not take effect in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, autocommit

I want to test a scene that insert about 100,000 datas, and find that if i set VARIABLES autocommit to zero and exec the stored procedures 1, and then reset autocommit to one, it only takes about 0.2sec; but if I extract circulation out of the stored procedures 1 as stored procedures 2, and exec it for 10000 times, it takes about 26sec, it looks like database still commit while call the stored procedures 2 each time even though autocommit is off. Why it happend? So appreciate for your answer.

stored procedures 1:

```
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0; 
SET i=0;
WHILE i<10000 DO
INSERT INTO `test_table` ( `objectType`, `addedDate`, `editedDate`) 
VALUES ('task','2017-11-17 15:44:23', '2017-11-17 15:44:23');
SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
```

stored procedures 2: call this sp for 10000 times

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` ( `objectType`, `addedDate`, `editedDate`) 
VALUES ('task','2017-11-17 15:44:23', '2017-11-17 15:44:23');

autocommit:OFF
```

Comment: Could you test if it's actually a problem with autocommit? Cancel the execution midway and see if contents are committed to the database?

Comment: autocommit:OFF is not a valid mysql command so sp2 should fail to compile.

Comment: If it takes 26000 milliseconds to do something 10000 times, that's 2.6ms each.  This *might* simply be the overhead of running the proc 10000 times.  You could benchmark that.  Autocommit is scoped to the session (connection) and should not be subject to variation related only to the depth of your call stack.

Comment: @Caramiriel Yes, the contents are committed to the database actually, and it seems like the para autocommit has lost efficacy.

Comment: @P.Salmon Maybe I do not describe it very clearly, in my sp I use it as: SET SESSION AUTOCOMMIT=0;

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Maybe the depth of 10000 times are not so suitable, but my emphasis is why the para autocommit lose efficacy while calling the sp2 outside? It seems like that while ending the sp2 each time it will commit the contents anyway even though the autocommit  is off.